Custom Stereotypes do not inherit appearance from superclass stereotypes
I am modelling in EA using Archimate 3. As Archimate is relatively bare-bones, and I need additional tagged values in my Archimate objects, I have created my own specializations of Archimate 3 stereotypes.
However, in order to retain the appearance of the Archimate 3 objects, I need to use Shape Scripts. Apparently the appearance of the Archimate 3 stereotypes is not automatically inherited by specializations. In particular, when I use GetUserFillColor() to determine the current fill color of an object, I do not get the color of the Stereotype I inherited from. However, when I use a custom SetFillColor() in my Shape Scripts I can no longer give individual objects in a diagram a different color (i.e. grey to indicate they are out of scope).
I tried to use GetUserFillColor() to get the original color of the stereotype. I would expect this to return the color of the stereotype I inherited from. That is not the case. I also do not see how to determine if the result of GetUserFillColor() is grey or not.

There are threads started by Paolo on the Sparxian forum IIRC. Also I seem to remember that inheriting shape script does not really work. Probably a bug-by-design :-/ Likely you have to re-implement shape scripts to adapt them manually as needed. Further the Sparxians have hard-coded several things (at least in SysML and some of their own profiles) which are agains human logic.

The default colors for ArchiMate elements are not defined in the shapescript.
In order to get the same color, you should set it as default color of your stereotype element.
You can set the default color of your stereotype element using F4

Then make sure you use the option Color and appearance when exporting to UML Profile.

You can check whether or not the background color has been saved in the profile by inspecting the xml file. Look for the attribute bgcolor

All of this is explained in the manual

I have tried this (using version 16.1). I applied the default background color to both the Metaclass I inherit from (an Archimate 3 stereotype) in the UML Profiel diagram, as well as to the inherited stereotype. I also commented out the SetFillColor in the shape script for the inherited stereotype. While I can now modify the fill color on an individual basis in one diagram, the objects now appear with a white background when I create them, not the default background color I assigned.

I don't know what to say. That is how it's supposed to work, and how I've done on on all of my UML profiles. You can check whether or not the color has come through in the xml file.

This is what I see in the XML: <Stereotype name="MyStereotypeName" notes="" cx="90" cy="70" bgcolor="-1", ...... generalises="Archimate3::ArchiMate_ApplicationService"...' So it would seem the background color does not end up in the XML.

Weirdly, fontcolor and borderwidth do end up in the XML, bgcolor and bordercolor do not.

And even more weirdly, fontsize ends up in the XML, but when changing back to the default, the modified value keeps appearing in the XML.

Are you generating your profile from the package, or the diagram? I always generate from package.

From the diagram. Would that make a difference?

Perhaps I'm not doing it correctly, but when I publish from Package, I get an non -1 background color in the XML export. I do, however, loose all shapescript info. I can change the fill color in the diagram, though.

In the manual you refer to it explicitly states "Color and Appearance - (enabled if saving the profile from a diagram; disabled if saving from a Package in the Browser window)". That fits with my observation that when I publish the stereotypes from the package, instead of from the diagram, I get the default UML representation, so without any shape script results.

I don't see what you are talking about. The page I linked doesn't contain the terms package or diagram. Anyhow, in all the MDG's I made I export UML profiles from the package, and I get both shapescripts as default "color and appearance".

You are right. That remark is from the "Export a Profile" help page. I'm wondering is there is some setting in Enterprise Architect (either when creating the MDG or when using the MDG)?  I made sure the "Color and Appearance" checkbox is checked.

I guess the color and appearance checkbox doesn't apply when generating from package.

I will give a detailed description of how I work. Perhaps that will highlight something that causes the issue I'm experiencing.
Part 1: I start with a Package that contains all my extension work. Inside that Package I have a number of additional packages:

Patterns
Diagram
Stereotypes
Toolbox


Part 2: In each of these Packages I have a diagram and the Elements that go in the diagram. It is these diagrams that I publish as Profile XML's, and it is here that I notice that the background color doesn't appear in the exported XML, but rather "-1".
In the Stereotypes Package I have the Stereotypes I inherit from, my custom Stereotypes, and my Enumerations. I have given my custom stereotypes a default background color (using F4)
After publishing my Profile XML's I create my MDG using a MTS file where I indicate the location of the different, relevant Profile XML's.

@RikvanderSchalie I think you should really stop exporting profiles from diagrams and use packages instead. But have you tried setting the local color, and checking the checkbox? I think that might work if you generate the profile from a diagram.

I've tried, but then I seem to loose all shape script effects (so plain UML boxes). Besides, for at least the Pattern Package, but also for the top-level package, the "Publish Package as UML Profile" is greyed out.

Then you should probably look into that. There's no reason the shapescripts shouldn't be included when exporting your UML profile from a package.

OK, I no longer have the disappearing Shape Script issue. That was caused by publishing the diagram and the package from the same package. As soon as I made a copy of the package it worked. However, when publishing from the package, I'm still not able to get a custom background color. When I turn "Show Shape Scripts" off in the Elements tab of the Diagram properties, I do see the custom colors but no shape script shapes. When I turn it on again, I see the Shape script shapes, but no longer the custom background color.

Check your xml file. Does it contain both the shapescript as the bgcolor? In that case the profile generation works fine. I guess then the background color is set hardcoded in the shapescript?

Yes, it does (although the shape script is encoded, so we cannot see what it does). We explicitly removed the setfillcolor from the shape script. I did just notice that, when I turn "Show Shape Scripts" in the Elements tab of the Diagram Properties off, our custom shapes (showing selected tagged values) remain visible. It's just the "shape main" part that is no longer shown.

What I also notice is that, in my "normal" diagrams, when I do F4 on an element, the background is "default", not the background of the stereotype, while the element color is correct. Just not changable..

It must still be in the shapescript, otherwise you could be able to change the background color. It is possible to decode the shapescript from a UML profile xml file if you really want to.

Turned out to be duplicate profile id's due to having a few different options side by side. cleaned it up, and now it all seems to work. Thanks!
